# Timestamp conflict for result set in db2

Tags: sql, db2

I'm trying to figure out how to take a valid result set and change the query to only return the most recent if there are more than one rows for an ID. Basically, an ID could have multiple status codes and I only want the most recent but I also need the code which messes up grouping or distinct

I have this

```
SELECT T . ITEM_ID , TS . NAME as STATUS, tts.row_change
FROM schema .ITEM T
INNER JOIN schema . ITEMT_TO_ITEM_STATUST TTS
    ON TTS.ITEMT_ID = T.ITEMT_ID
INNER JOIN schema  . ITEM_STATUST TS
    ON TS . ITEM_STATUST_ID = TTS . ITEM_STATUST_ID;
```

which gives me this:

```
ID  |  STATUS  |  row_change
-----------------------------------------
125     P           2019-08-25 12:00:00
125     A           2019-08-25 12:08:00
123     P           2019-08-25 12:00:00
```

Which is technically correct, but now what I want/need.

How can I alter this to get the row for ID 123 but then the row for ID 125 that has the 12:08 timestamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
SELECT T.ITEM_ID, TS.NAME as STATUS, tts.row_change
FROM schema.ITEM T JOIN
     (SELECT TTS.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TTS.ITEMT_ID ORDER BY tts.row_change DESC) as seqnum
      FROM schema.ITEMT_TO_ITEM_STATUST TTS
     ) TTS
     ON TTS.ITEMT_ID = T.ITEMT_ID JOIN
     schema.ITEM_STATUST TS
     ON TS.ITEM_STATUST_ID = TTS.ITEM_STATUST_ID
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Had to change the order by to desc in order to get the most recent but this worked! Thank you so much